# Simple Rails routes questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have

```
resources :calendars do

   resources :blocked_times

end
```

What is the helper method that will generate `/calendar/:calendar_id/blocked_times` ?

I tried `calendar_blocked_time_path(@calendar.id)` but that gave me:

```
/calendar/:calendar_id/blocked_times/:blocked_time_id
```

And the :blocked_time_id is defaulted to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those routes in place run `rake routes` and you'll get an output of the names of the routes.

Though I think in this case you're looking for:

```
calendar_blocked_times_path(@calendar)
```

I haven't tested this, but basically for the index action you want a plural for the second resource.

Comment: Thanks bro :) Routes can bend the mind a bit. Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you :D

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a nested route, you'll need in more than one argument to `calendar_blocked_time_path` in order to route to the correct `BlockTime`:

```
calendar_block_time_path(@calendar, @blocked_time)
```

If you want to get the `index` action for the `BlockTimesController`, use the following path, passing *only* the `Calendar` `id`:

```
calendar_block_times_path(@calendar)
```

Notice that, since you're trying to access a plural resource (block times, in this case), you'll want to invoke the pluralize form of the resource – that is, `calendar_block_times`.

Remember that you can always run `rake routes` from the command line to get a full host of the routes and their corresponding paths. Here's the output in your case:

```
       calendar_blocked_times GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/blocked_times(.:format)          blocked_times#index
                              POST   /calendars/:calendar_id/blocked_times(.:format)          blocked_times#create
    new_calendar_blocked_time GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/blocked_times/new(.:format)      blocked_times#new
   edit_calendar_blocked_time GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/blocked_times/:id/edit(.:format) blocked_times#edit
        calendar_blocked_time GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/blocked_times/:id(.:format)      blocked_times#show
                              PUT    /calendars/:calendar_id/blocked_times/:id(.:format)      blocked_times#update
                              DELETE /calendars/:calendar_id/blocked_times/:id(.:format)      blocked_times#destroy
                    calendars GET    /calendars(.:format)                                     calendars#index
                              POST   /calendars(.:format)                                     calendars#create
                 new_calendar GET    /calendars/new(.:format)                                 calendars#new
                edit_calendar GET    /calendars/:id/edit(.:format)                            calendars#edit
                     calendar GET    /calendars/:id(.:format)                                 calendars#show
                              PUT    /calendars/:id(.:format)                                 calendars#update
                              DELETE /calendars/:id(.:format)                                 calendars#destroy
```

As you'll notice, the correct path to a calendar block time is `/calendars/:calendar_id/blocked_times/:id`. The first argument passed to `calendar_block_time_path` is the `:calendar_id`, and the second argument passed is `:id` – that is, the `id` of the `BlockTime`.

Comment: Hmm, how do you get it to display the helper function next to it? When I rake routes all I get is the HTTP method type and the URL format

Comment: Hmm... it's possible that you're on a smaller terminal window, or part of your terminal window isn't showing. Have you tried to copy and paste the contents of `rake routes` to verify whether or not the entire contents are being printed?

Comment: Yes 755, maybe make your terminal window wider (longer routes will wrap onto multiple lines which can confuse things).

Comment: @755, glad it helped. BrandonMuir rightfully got the accept for posting the same answer first, but if this answer and commentary were helpful, please consider upvoting it.